# JS get time difference to UNIX timestamp or the timestamps date

Tags: javascript, datetime, mobile, time, unix-timestamp

I have some elements with UNIX timestamps inside, which is not useful for clients. So i transform them into

- less then one minute ago = "just now"
- less then one hour ago = "X minutes ago"
- less then a day ago = "X hours ago"
- else: "timestamp->real date".

First of all my code works, **BUT** not on mobile devices such as iPhone5s. The result with these devices will be: **NaN NaN NaN NaN**. I'd love to know how to fix this.

The other thing is, my javascript looks pretty stupid, I think. But I could not figure out how to loop through these different time-conditions. Suggestions here are not necessary but grateful appreciated.

**NOTE: I cannot change the structure of my paragraphs before the page is loaded. It is set that my paragraphs will contain UNIX timestamps. Thats my starting position.**

here comes my full html with loads of < p > examples, **copy & paste ready:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<script>
    function startTime() {

        var dates = document.getElementsByClassName('date');

        for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {

            var currentdate = Date.now();

            if (dates[i].innerHTML !== '') {

                var date = new Date(dates[i].innerHTML*1000);

                if (currentdate - 60000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "just now"}
                else if (currentdate - 120000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "1 min ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 180000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "2 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 240000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "3 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 300000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "4 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 360000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "5 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 420000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "6 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 480000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "7 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 540000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "8 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 600000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "9 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 660000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "10 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 720000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "11 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 780000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "12 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 840000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "13 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 900000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "14 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 960000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "15 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 1020000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "16 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 1080000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "17 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 1140000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "18 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 1200000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "19 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 1260000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "20 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 1320000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "21 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 1380000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "22 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 1440000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "23 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 1500000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "24 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 1560000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "25 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 1620000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "26 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 1680000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "27 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 1740000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "28 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 1800000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "29 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 1860000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "30 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 1920000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "31 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 1980000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "32 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 2040000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "33 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 2100000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "34 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 2160000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "35 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 2220000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "36 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 2280000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "37 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 2340000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "38 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 2400000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "39 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 2460000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "40 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 2520000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "41 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 2580000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "42 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 2640000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "43 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 2700000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "44 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 2760000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "45 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 2820000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "46 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 2880000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "47 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 2940000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "48 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 3000000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "49 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 3060000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "50 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 3120000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "51 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 3180000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "52 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 3240000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "53 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 3300000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "54 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 3360000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "55 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 3420000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "56 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 3480000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "57 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 3540000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "58 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 3600000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "59 mins ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 7320000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "1 hr ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 10980000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "2 hrs ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 14640000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "3 hrs ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 18300000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "4 hrs ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 21960000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "5 hrs ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 25620000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "6 hrs ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 29280000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "7 hrs ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 32940000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "8 hrs ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 36600000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "9 hrs ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 40260000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "10 hrs ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 43920000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "11 hrs ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 47580000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "12 hrs ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 51240000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "13 hrs ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 54900000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "14 hrs ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 58560000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "15 hrs ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 62220000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "16 hrs ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 65880000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "17 hrs ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 69540000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "18 hrs ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 73200000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "19 hrs ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 76860000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "20 hrs ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 80520000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "21 hrs ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 84180000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "22 hrs ago"}
                else if (currentdate - 87840000 <= date) {dates[i].innerHTML = "23 hrs ago"}
                else {

                    var year = date.getFullYear();
                    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                    var day = date.getDate();
                    var formattedTime = day + "." + month + "." + year;

                    dates[i].innerHTML = formattedTime;

                }   
            }
        }
    }
</script>

</head>


<body onload="startTime();">

<p class="date">1483015785</p>
<p class="date">1483015786</p>
<p class="date">1483015794</p>
<p class="date">1483015984</p>
<p class="date">1483019784</p>
<p class="date">1483095784</p>
<p class="date">1489915784</p>
<p class="date">1483015927</p>
<p class="date">1483015918</p>
<p class="date">1483015917</p>
<p class="date">1483015728</p>
<p class="date">1483013928</p>
<p class="date">1483012928</p>
<p class="date">1483011928</p>
<p class="date">1483010928</p>
<p class="date">1483011428</p>
<p class="date">1483031228</p>
<p class="date">712619600</p>
<p class="date">716165789</p>
<p class="date">451616960</p>
<p class="date">567845845</p>
<p class="date">767856785</p>
<p class="date">867985764</p>

</body>
</html>
```

## UPDATE:

I did a little bit more research, as it turns out the **problem occurs because mobile Safari automatically turns certain numbers into links!**

example:

```
<p>1484234234234</p>
automatically becomes
<p><a href="tel:1484234234234">1484234234234</a></p>
```

Thats at least why my code isn't working. Strange is, that not all numbers will be converted, as you can find out with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function startTime() {
        var dates = document.getElementsByClassName('date');    
        for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
            if (dates[i].innerHTML !== '') {
                var date = dates[i].innerHTML;
                alert(date);
    }}}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="startTime();">

<!--first two will be converted-->
    <p class="date">1483015785</p>
    <p class="date">1483015786</p>
<!--these two won't-->
    <p class="date">712619600</p>
    <p class="date">716165789</p>
</body>
</html>
```

for now I couldn't find a solution for this problem. changing the < p > to something else  ( < date > f.e.) doesn't help.

Comment: https://neilsteventon.wordpress.com/2014/11/17/javascript-new-date-nan-on-iphone/

Comment: Debug your code until you find out what line starts the NaN --- post a simple test case here instead of your full code so that future readers can quickly see the issue / answer.

Comment: the NaN occurs in all if/else if conditions. only the last else will give me the results i want. But i do not understand why, since it works fine cross browsers on my computer with all conditions. My example is online here, by the way: https://adventuretrails.000webhostapp.com

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you mean, but I'm saying reword your question such that you have like two lines: `var currentdate = Date.now()` returns a valid date `var subtractionresult = currentdate - 1200000` returns NaN --- this is what I am assuming is happening without testing it myself; if someone glances at your question it helps to have a concise question, which I think is very possible here. (*Note: I'm reviewing your question, not necessarily answering it)

Comment: found out something quite interesting as you can see in my update, i think. But it's not enough to solve the problem, for now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding this line to the head of my html the transformation will be prevented:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
```

**possible problem: that line addresses all numbers in my document**

That means if I want to make numbers callable on click for phones I need to highlight them myself.

Also i don't know what else this line effects.